# Information about a given DSA Key

Tags: ssh, security, dsa

Reading the answer https://superuser.com/a/13189/246855 to the question [What is better for GPG keys - RSA or DSA?](https://superuser.com/questions/13164/what-is-better-for-gpg-keys-rsa-or-dsa), I decided to examine the 2048 bit DSA key I use to figure out which secure hash algorithm was used to create the key.

However, I am unable to figure out how to find out the function used to generate the key, as Google and `ssh-keygen` and `openssl dsa` give me nothing.

In summary, what command do I run to figure out the Secure hash function used to generate a given 2048 bit DSA key.

Comment: I advise you to look at these 2 answers:
http://security.stackexchange.com/a/29312/9792
http://security.stackexchange.com/a/23385/9792 .
You might receive better answers on http://security.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @danielAzuelos This question is more on an command rather than security theory, thus I posted it here instead of security.stackexchange.